# Unknown type name string C++

Tags: c++, string

I'm new to C++ and have had some help with my program to compare two XML files.  This is the code I have:

```
#include "pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml"))
        return 1;

    for (auto& node: doca.child("site_entries").children("entry")) {
        const char* id = node.child_value("id");
        mapa[new std::string(id, strlen(id))] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child("site_entries").children("entry"))
        const char* idcs = node.child_value("id");
        std::string id = new std::string(idcs, strlen(idcs));
        if (!mapa.erase(id)) {
            mapb[id] = node;
        }
    }

}
```

I seem to get a lot of errors when I try and compile it.

The first one I get is this:

```
src/main.cpp:10:14: error: unknown type name 'string'; did you mean 'std::string'?
    std::map<string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;
        ~~~~~^~~
```

From what I understand, I have specified it correctly. Should I change it as it requests or is something else a-miss?

Comment: you must include <string> to use std::string

Comment: You need to specify it as std::string if you want to use string of the c++ std namespace.

Comment: or the un-recommanded `using namesapce std;`.

Comment: Additionally, the use of the new operator is not needed here. std::string id(idcs... is better

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to include the string library in order to use `std::string`.

Since you mentioned a *lot of errors*, I suspect you forgot to include `<cstring>` in order to use `strlen()`.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to include the string library:

```
#include <string>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following way:

`std::string varName = "var value";`

I'm using Clion IDE and it worked for me.