# C++ Card Shuffler Errors

Tags: c++

The instructions are:

Create a program to shuffle and deal a deck of cards. The program should consist of class Card, class DeckOfCards and a driver program.

**Class Card should provide:**
a) Data members face and suit of type int.
b) A constructor that receives two ints representing the face and suit and uses them to initialize the data members.

**Class DeckOfCards should contain:**
a) Two Card objects named deck to store two cards.
b) A constructor that takes no arguments and initializes both cards in the deck.
You can give these two cards a random face value and suit value, but make sure they are not the same.
c) A printCards function that prints the two cards.

The driver program should create a DeckOfCards object, and print the cards that this object has.

**You need to have 5 files in this project: card.hpp, card.cpp, deckofcards.hpp, deckofcards.cpp, main.cpp**

The errors I get are:

1. explicit type is missing('int' assumed) in DeckOfCards.h line 15

   2. no suitable constructor exists to convert from "DeckOfCards*" to "DeckOfCards" in main.cpp line 8
   3. missing type specifier -int assumed in DeckOfCards.h line 15
   4. 'initializing': cannot convert from 'DeckOfCards*' to 'DeckOfCards' in main.cpp line 8
   5. missing type specifier- int assumed in DeckOfCards.h line 15
   6. missing type specifier- int assumed in DeckOfCards.cpp line 18

Card.h:

```
#ifndef Card_H
#define Card_H
#include <string>

using namespace std;


string suits[4] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Spades", "Clubs" };
string faces[12] = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

class Card {
public:
    int face;
    int suit;
    Card(int face, int suit);
    string toString();
};

#endif
```

Card.cpp:

```
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Card::Card(int face, int suit) {
    this->face = face;
    this->suit = suit;
}

string Card::toString() {
    string suitname = suits[suit];
    string facename = faces[face];

    return facename + " of " + suitname;
}
```

DeckOfCards.h:

```
#ifndef DeckOfCards_H
#define DeckOfCards_H
#include "Card.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


class DeckOfCards {
public:
    vector<Card> deck;

public:
    DeckOfCards();
    printCards();
};

#endif
```

DeckOfCards.cpp:

```
#include "DeckofCards.h"
#include "Card.h"
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::string;


DeckOfCards::DeckOfCards() {

    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        Card card(i + 3, i + 5);
        deck.push_back(card);
    }
}

DeckOfCards::printCards() {
    for (int i = 0; i<2; i++) {
        cout << deck[i].toString();
    }
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"
#include "DeckOfCards.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    DeckOfCards cardDeck = new DeckOfCards();
    cardDeck.printCards();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what exact part of the very clear "Unknown type name 'string' in Card.hpp" error message you didn't understand?

Comment: Why does your deck have only 48 cards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unknown type name string C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29692326/unknown-type-name-string-c)

Answer (score 0):

To use the std::string class you have to include the header file string, so to import it to the corresponding hpp file, you need to write this

```
#include <string>
```

now instead of always typing std::string you can add

```
using std::string;
```

before you program out the class